# Checkout loader keeps loading in Magento 2.3.7

Tags: magento2

When I try to checkout the purchase it keeps loading all the time. My question is about purchase page loading issue. I've checked the console & there is error like this:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "scope: function(){return '' }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return getTemplate() }"
>   Message: getTemplate is not defined
>   at template (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:61)
>   at init (knockout.js:5454)
>   at knockout.js:3358
>   at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1470)
>   at knockout.js:3357
>   at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
>   at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3343)
>   at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3223)
>   at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3205)
>   at Object.ko.applyBindingsToDescendants (knockout.js:3421)
> ```

PHP version: 7.4

Magento version: 2.3.7

Theme version: Pearl Theme for Magento 2 Open Source v1.10.15 (Aug 31, 2021)

Expected results: After click on checkout button, checkout page should be open.

Received result: Checkout loader keeps loading, after a click on proceed to the checkout page.

Comment: You should ask the theme vendor instead, I don't think it's related to Magento Core.

Comment: Yes, Issue with pearl theme. But please suggest, how to rectify.

Comment: You may report the issue to the vendor of pearl theme. Maybe you may do it via themeforest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading magento version to 2.4.2 its working as expected.